# Combining classes in Android

Tags: java, android, opencv

So I am now working on an Android project which basically takes the video stream from a camera mounted on a drone, and then uses OpenCV techniques to process the stream and do something. The problem for me now is that I have 2 separate projects each does one of the jobs mentioned above. The class structure of my 2 projects are as follows: [image: UML]

This is just like the standard workflow: you have a surface element in the xml, and then the corresponding one in the activity source file. The FPV project works to retrieve video stream from the drone to the phone, while the Color Blob project retrieves the stream from the phone camera and does something to it(OpenCV).

Now my question is how to efficiently solve this merge problem so that I can retrieve the video stream from the drone and do something to it as in the Color Blob project? I am not proficient in Java so I would like to hear some other voice before diving into this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you want to merge them?  One thought would be to put the guts of the FPV project in a background thread or service that would receive the stream from the drone, and break it down into image frames  and put them in some kind of queue, it could start throwing away frames if the queue got too full.  Your Color Blob detection program could take frames out of queue and provide views for both the raw frames from the drone and the processed images you run through opencv operations.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a new project ,

1. Add in all the necessary dependencies.
2. Add in the classes from both project
3. Using the main class(or another class) to act as a logic layer for calling classes

Essentially , you are attempting to merge the 2 main class and sort out the sequential flow .

Hope this can get you started.